# Why objects like NSString and NSNumber cannot be overwritten?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, immutability, mutable

There are many posts about the same topic and it may be a stupid question, but I haven't been able to understand this concept.

I know the problems presented when you assign a mutable string to a immutable one, and why I should use copy to avoid these problems.

What I don't really understand is: what does exactly mean that a  NSString cannot be modified?

If I do this:

```
NSString *foo = @"Hello World!";
foo = @"Hello everybody!";
```

I understand I'm not modifying foo's value, but rather replacing the old instance with a new one. But then, how is it defined that I cannot rewrite a mutable object?

**UPDATE**
I tried running the following code:

```
-(void)immutable
{
    NSString *myString1 = @"Hello!";
    NSString *myString2 = myString1;

    NSLog(@"myString1 address: %p", &myString1); //Prints 0xbfffdb30
    NSLog(@"myString2 address: %p", &myString2); //Prints 0xbfffdb2c

    myString2 = @"Good bye!";
    NSLog(@"myString2 address: %p", &myString2); //Prints 0xbfffdb2c

    NSMutableString *myMutableString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Hello"];
    NSString *myString3 = myMutableString;

    NSLog(@"myMutableString address: %p", &myMutableString); //Prints 0xbfffdb28
    NSLog(@"myString3 address: %p", &myString3); //Prints 0xbfffdb24

    [myMutableString setString:@"Hello World"];
    NSLog(@"myString3: %@", myString3); //Prints Hello World

    myString3 = myString1;
    NSLog(@"myString3 address: %p", &myString3); //Prints 0xbfffdb24

    [myMutableString setString:@"Nothing to do"];
    NSLog(@"myString3: %@", myString3); //Prints Hello!
}
```

I am not surprised that the address of myString1 and myString2 are different, since both are immutable objects. But even after assigning a different string to myString2, it is still pointing to the same address as before. Shouldn't it change?

But in the case of myMutableString and myString3, they still have different addresses even though any change in myMutableString will be reflected in myString3.
After I assign myString1 to myString3 the address myString3 is pointing doesn't change, but then it's no longer related with myMutableString, since every change I make to it will no longer be reflected in myString3. 
What is causing myString3 and myMutableString be linked in the first place?

Comment: `&myString` gets you the address of the local pointer, not the address of the object. Set a breakpoint at the start of the method and watch the adresses of the objects in the debugging pane.

Comment: Thank you! I got pretty confused by the results of the test, but now everything is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `foo = @"Hello World!";`, foo was pointing to an `NSString` object that has the data `"Hello World!"`, let's say that this object resides at address 10.

When you write `foo = @"Hello everybody!"`, `foo` now points to a new object that has the data `"Hello everybody!"`, let's say that this object resides at address 50. The first object wasn't modified at all, you just made foo point to another object at another address.

If those strings were mutable, you could modify the content,

```
NSMutableString *foo = @"Hello World!".mutableCopy; //LEt's say, it's @ adress 10
[foo appendString:@"How is it going?"]; // IT's still @ adress 10, but with new content.
```

foo now points to an object at address 10, that has modified content `"Hello World!How is it going?"`.

In the first case, you couldn't modify `NSString` because it doesn't give you any methods to change the data at that address. That's immutability. `NSMutableString` on the other hand gives you that ability, by methods like `appendString:` and `appendString:`. This way you can change the contents of the object at the same address without having to create a new object to make those changes.

Comment: Great answer, I've made some small edits. As a comment in general, in terms of usage, `NSMutableString` isn't really used. Generally we make a copy of the string or append it. Mutable objects are mostly used  for `NSMutableArray` and `NSMutableDictionary` (there are others, but those are the two most common), because you'll probably need dynamic arrays and dictionaries quite often. But if you use those, remember to sometimes pass a `copy` if those are part of your public API. If you don't want anyone to mess up the mutable objects, make them immutable. Or vice-versa with `mutableCopy`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I update the question with some code I tried, but it didn't work as I was expecting after reading your answer.

Comment: @Lovato You're right about the mutable data containers. Mutable strings can be useful if you need to build up a string from a scratch and by many steps. For example, building a a URL by adding parameters by checking if each parameter should be added or not.